# How do I fix ' running in low graphics mode' Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Brand new Lemur Ultra arrived this evening on my doorstep. I turned it on and followed the instructions. Hadn't even finished starting up then it gave the warning 'running in low graphics mode' and goes to a screen which gives me four options;
1. Run in low graphics mode for just one session
2. Recofigure graphics
3. Troubleshoot error
4. Exit to console login

There are two options at the bottom, Cancel and OK.

Problem is the user interface is dead. I cannot execute any option. If I re-start, it just comes back o the same page.

Help!